# How to conveniently install uninstalled packages found in library() calls in a script in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose I'm given a script with a bunch of packages, some of which I already have installed and others I don't, is there a quick/easy way (keyboard shortcut perhaps?) to make RStudio 1. recognise the `library()` calls, and 2. install any packages that aren't already installed?

Note: I recall a small notification used to appear toward to the top of the RStudio script pane, but it doesn't seem to happen for me -- perhaps that feature was removed or I need to do something to trigger it.

An example of a script with a lot of `library()` calls:

```r
library(shiny) # not installed
library(shinydashboard) # not installed
library(dplyr) # already installed
library(tm) # etc etc
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(wordcloud2)
library(tidyr)
# Truncated for brevity
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found one way is to **save the script**, that will trigger the notification offering to install uninstalled packages:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These approaches are not dependent on R Studio or any other infrastructure other than R itself.  If you give the script to someone else they will still work even if they are not using R Studio.

**1)** Define your own library function at the top of the script which checks if the package named in the package argument is installed and if not installs it.  Note that require, used in this script, loads the package if it is present and then returns TRUE.  It returns FALSE if the package was not present.

```
library <- function(package, ...) {
  pkg <- as.character(substitute(package))
  if (!require(pkg, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE, ...)) {
    install.packages(pkg)
    base::library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, ...)
  }
}
```

**2)** If it is good enough to be notified if a package is not installed then you don't have to do anything as the ordinary library statement will fail if the package is not installed halting the script and effectively notifying you to install it with a message such as the following which identifies the uninstalled package.

```
Error in library(xyz) : there is no package called ‘xyz’
```

If you go this route make sure that either there are no package redundancies in the library statements or at least that the library statements for dependencies come after the packages that depend on them.  This is only to optimize installation iterations and you don't need to do it if you are willing to risk having additional iterations if multiple dependent packages are not installed.

For example, from the dependency relationships below we see that to minimize installation iterations the library statement for dplyr should come after that for tidyr and the library statement for tidyr should come after that for tidyverse.  Also the library statement for shiny should come after that for shinydashboard.  (Can use the R function tsort from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort which will accept deps and produce a possible ordering for those packages but we can just do it by inspecting deps or without deps at all and just relying on our knowledge of those packages.)

```
library(tools)

p <- c("shiny", "shinydashboard", "dplyr", "tm", "wordcloud", 
  "memoise", "janeaustenr", "tidyverse", "tidytext", "wordcloud2", 
  "tidyr")
deps <- Filter(length, Map(function(x) intersect(dependsOnPkgs(x), p), p))
deps
## $shiny
## [1] "shinydashboard"
##
## $dplyr
## [1] "tidyr"     "tidyverse"
##
## $tidyr
## [1] "tidyverse"

tsort(deps)
## [1] "shinydashboard" "tidyverse"      "shiny"          "tidyr"         
## [5] "dplyr"
```

Comment: For what it’s worth I strongly recommend against doing this, and not just because it overrides an existing function with a new functionality: package management and code should be separated, e.g. using ‘renv’. (Also, this is missing `character.only = TRUE`),

Comment: This is what was asked for.  There is no reason to over-complicate and over-engineer this and add yet another package dependency when a 3 line function will do it.  If you really want to go to the next level make the script into a package.

Comment: Have fixed library function.